# getting memory leak in [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] in instrument with ARC enable project

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

Getting wired memory leak on `NSNumberFormatter` in my project.

While i am checking my app in `Instrument` i am getting many framework leaks and one of very surprising leak was `NSNumberFormatter` leak while I am allocing that formatter object.

**Here is my function to formatting my Number value:**

```
//Set Number Formatter - Like 1000 = 1,000
+ (NSString *)getNumberWithNumberFormate:(NSString*)dataVal{
    NSNumberFormatter *aNumberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [aNumberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSString *aFormattedNumber = [aNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[dataVal doubleValue]]];
    aNumberFormatter = nil;
    return aFormattedNumber;
}
```

while I am checking memory leak it will show

```
NSNumberFormatter *aNumberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
```

This line as leak.

I have also `nil` this object after my formatting done.

```
aNumberFormatter = nil;
```

still memory leak is there.

any idea to resolve this leak.

**Check this instrument screenshot.**[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for your case you no need set instance to nil `aNumberFormatter = nil`
The instance of `NSNumberFormatter` will destroy after `getNumberWithNumberFormate` class method will out of scope.
Try to modify a bit your method to

```
+ (NSString *)getNumberWithNumberFormate:(NSString*)dataVal{
    NSNumberFormatter *aNumberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [aNumberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSString *aFormattedNumber = [aNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[dataVal doubleValue]]];
    return aFormattedNumber;
}
```

Also the good practice use `static` instance and `dispatch_once` for formatter like below

```
+ (NSString *)getNumberWithNumberFormate:(NSString*)dataVal{
    static NSNumberFormatter *aNumberFormatter = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        aNumberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [aNumberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    });
    NSString *aFormattedNumber = [aNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[dataVal doubleValue]]];
    return aFormattedNumber;
}
```

In this example you will use only one instance for every time of using this class method and will decrease memory usage

Answer for comment and clear debugging try to check this code

```
+ (NSString *)getNumberWithNumberFormate:(NSString*)dataVal{
    NSString *copyDataValue = [dataVal copy];
    double dataValueDouble = [copyDataValue doubleValue];
    static NSNumberFormatter *aNumberFormatter = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        aNumberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [aNumberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    });
    NSString *aFormattedNumber = [aNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(dataValueDouble)];
    return aFormattedNumber;
}
```

Comment: suggestion is quite near to resolve memory leak its solve my first leak but still `NSString *aFormattedNumber = [aNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[dataVal doubleValue]]];` line giving me leak in instrument. any idea why ?

Comment: So for this issue I can just suggest. So I updated answer. Please try it

Comment: its resolved my memory leak but can you explain why you make `copy` & `convert` it into `doublevalue` I am very eager to know logic behind this conversion ?

Comment: I make copy (it create new instance of param) for incapsulate string param and it help to work inside method only with this instance. It's guarantee me that entering param will not random change at runtime.`doubleValue` just convert string and return double that you using this value  in `stringFromNumber` method

Comment: Ok Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123002/discussion-between-dhanesh-and-isashok).